# Approximate Matching and Replacement in Text R

Tags: r, text, matching, fuzzy-search

I have one sentence where I want to replace only a part of a string with a number. If we have an exact match the gsub function works perfectly.

```
gsub('great thing', 5555 ,c('hey this is a great thing'))
gsub('good rabbit', 5555 ,c('hey this is a good rabbit in the field'))
```

But now I have the following problem. How can I apply a fuzzy matching function to a string if there is a mistake in the part of the string?

```
gsub('great thing', 5555 ,c('hey this is a graet thing'))
gsub('good rabbit', 5555 ,c('hey this is a goood rabit in the field'))
```

The algorithm should figure out that "great thing" and "graet thing" or "good rabbit" and "goood rabit" are very similiar and should be replaced with the number 5555. Best if we can use the Jaro Winkler distance to find an approximate matching within the string and then replacing the approximate substring. I need a very abstract alogrithm wich can do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps `gsub('gr[ae][ae]t thing', 5555 ,c('hey this is a graet thing'))`

Comment: `agrep` for the win!

Comment: well, I was thinking of applying a fuzzy matching algorithm with the jaro winkler distance. Is this possible?

Comment: You may check `library(stringdist)`  It has some options.

Comment: @akrun But what if it's "greatt thing"? You can't write a regex condition for each possibility.

Comment: @user3932000  Based on the distance methods, may be it would match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some `agrep` examples:

```
agrep("lasy", "1 lazy 2")
agrep("lasy", "1 lazy 2", max = list(sub = 0))
agrep("laysy", c("1 lazy", "1", "1 LAZY"), max = 2)
agrep("laysy", c("1 lazy", "1", "1 LAZY"), max = 2, value = TRUE)
agrep("laysy", c("1 lazy", "1", "1 LAZY"), max = 2, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

`agrep` is in base. If you load `stringdist` you can calculate string-distance using Jarro-Winkler with (you guessed) `stringdist` or if you're lazy you can just use `ain` or `amatch`. For my purposes, I tend to use  Damerau–Levenshtein (`method="dl"`) more, but your mileage might vary.

Just make sure to read up on exactly how the algorithm's parameters work before you use it (i.e. set your p, q and maxDist values to levels that make sense given what you're doing)

Comment: and how can I replace a substring with something if a similiarity is detected?

Comment: That's tougher. I'd probably use some n-grams of the to-be-searched string and compare that to the target string, calculating the Levenshtein distance. Keep track of which n-gram is which, and reconstruct the vector with the gsub switch. Sorry, can't think of a package that has this wrapped already. Perhaps tm or qdap?

Comment: Or see this answer to a similar question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843171/position-of-approximate-substring-matches-in-r

Comment: Thank you! This helps me a lot.