# Position of Approximate Substring Matches in R

Tags: r, fuzzy-comparison

I'm using R for string processing. I have a data frame with a column of strings, say:

```
 df <- data.frame(textcol=c("In this substring would like to find the position of this substring",
 "I would also like to find the position of thes substring",
 "No match here","No mention of this substrangy thing"))

 matchPattern <- "this substring"
```

I am searching for a function that (depending on a distance parameter of some sort, say Jarro-Winkler) would take my matchPattern, compare it to every row of the data frame text column, and return the exact position of the match within the matched string, i.e. 36 (unless I miscounted) for the first element, and (perhaps) 43 for the second, NA for the third and 14 (?) for the the fourth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `aregexec`

```
## Get positions (-1 instead of NA)
positions <- aregexec(matchPattern, df$textcol, max.distance = 0.1)
unlist(positions)
# [1] 38 43 -1 15

## Extract matches
regmatches(df$textcol, positions)
# [[1]]
# [1] "this substring"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "thes substring"
# 
# [[3]]
# character(0)
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "this substrang"
```

#### Edit

```
## A possibilty for replacing matches, or maybe `regmatches<-`
res <- regmatches(df$textcol, positions)
res[lengths(res)==0] <- "XXXX"  # deal with 0 length matches somehow
df$out <- Vectorize(gsub)(unlist(res), "Censored", df$textcol)
df$out
# [1] "I would like to find the position of Censored"     
# [2] "I would also like to find the position of Censored"
# [3] "No match here"                                     
# [4] "No mention of Censoredy thing"
```

Comment: Thanks nongkrong! Could you give a *very* brief sense of how that works? I've tried using aregexec before and was miffed.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa do you mean the algorithm for matching?  because I have no idea, but from `?agrep` it looks to use the Levenshtein distance.

Comment: No, no, simply assuming I want to replace each instance with 'Censored' in the original data.frame. For instance if the pattern is repeated more than once in one case.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa there is a replacement function, `regmatches<-` that you could probably use.  If you look at `?regmatches` there is an example of how to construct replacements at the bottom.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa you could also consider using `gsub`, I added an example