# Extract strings based on multiple patterns

Tags: r, gsub, stringr, stringdist

I have thousands of DNA sequences that look like this :).

```
ref <- c("CCTACGGTTATGTACGATTAAAGAAGATCGTCAGTC", "CCTACGCGTTGATATTTTGCATGCTTACTCCCAGTC", 
         "CCTCGCGTTGATATTTTGCATGCTTACTCCCAGTC")
```

I need to extract every sequence between the
**CTACG**  and  **CAGTC**.  However, many cases in these sequences come with an error
(deletion, insertion, substitution). Is there any way to account for mismatches based on Levenshtein distance?

```r
ref <- c("CCTACGGTTATGTACGATTAAAGAAGATCGTCAGTC", "CCTACGCGTTGATATTTTGCATGCTTACTCCCAGTC", 
         "CCTCGCGTTGATATTTTGCATGCTTACTCCCAGTC")

qdapRegex::ex_between(ref, "CTACG", "CAGTC")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "GTTATGTACGATTAAAGAAGATCGT"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "CGTTGATATTTTGCATGCTTACTCC"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] NA

reprex()
#> Error in reprex(): could not find function "reprex"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Like this I would be able to extract the sequence also in the last case.

**UPDATE:** can I create a dictionary with a certain Levenshtein distance and then match it to each sequence?

Comment: See [Position of Approximate Substring Matches in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843171/).

Comment: Try blast or clustalW. Or [msa](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/msa/inst/doc/msa.pdf)

Comment: uff, not quite sure R in itself is the optimal tool here, without some bioinformatics extensions, as @AndreWildberg recommended. QDAP doesn't seem to me to be the tool of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `aregexec`, build a regex pattern with `sprintf`, and finally removing the matches using `gsub`. Putting it into a `Vectorize`d function to avoid overloading the script with `lapply`s or loops.

In the regex, the `.*` refers to everything before (resp. after) the respective letters. Note, that you probably need to adapt the `max.distance=` with your real data.

```
fu <- Vectorize(function(x) {
  p1 <- regmatches(x, aregexec('.*CTACG', x, max.distance=0.1))
  p2 <- regmatches(x, aregexec('CAGTC.*', x, max.distance=0.1))
  gsub(sprintf('%s|%s', p1, p2), '', x, perl=TRUE)
})

fu(ref)
# CCTACGGTTATGTACGATTAAAGAAGATCGTCAGTC CCTACGCGTTGATATTTTGCATGCTTACTCCCAGTC 
#          "GTTATGTACGATTAAAGAAGATCGT"          "CGTTGATATTTTGCATGCTTACTCC" 
# CCTCGCGTTGATATTTTGCATGCTTACTCCCAGTC 
#          "CGTTGATATTTTGCATGCTTACTCC"
```

---

*Data:*

```
ref <- c("CCTACGGTTATGTACGATTAAAGAAGATCGTCAGTC", "CCTACGCGTTGATATTTTGCATGCTTACTCCCAGTC", 
         "CCTCGCGTTGATATTTTGCATGCTTACTCCCAGTC")
```

Comment: I want to invite you at least 10 beers. Thanks for taking the time

Comment: You're welcome @LDT, and I probably wouldn't turn down your invitation ;)